# entity framework returning different result when predicate is passed

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4.1

```
string personName= "JoHn";  
//(in my table iam already having a person named='john')

Func<Person, bool> predicate = (p) => p.Name== personName;

var res2 = dataContext.Persons.Any(predicate);                //returns false
var res1 = dataContext.Persons.Any(p=>p.Name== personName);   // returns true
```

I think with predicate its considering `case` of `personName` property while without it its just ignoring `case`.

Any one know why??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `Func<Page, bool>` is a delegate, which means you are running this in LINQ-to-Objects (i.e. in memory, in C#). .NET strings **are** case sensitive, so this will apply case.

This version, however:

```
var res1 = dataContext.Persons.Any(p=>p.Name== personName);
```

is using `IQueryable<T>` and expression-trees; it will be executed as a TSQL filter, which will apply database rules. What happens here depends on how your DB is configured (it could be either case-sensitive or case-insensitive, depending on the database).

If you want them both to use the same logic, then note the difference here:

```
Expression<Func<Page, bool>> predicate = (p) => p.Name== personName;
var res2 = dataContext.Persons.Any(predicate);
```

The addition of `Expression<...>` makes this an *expression-tree*, not a *delegate*, so it is "composed" and executed at the database (via TSQL translation), exactly the same as:

```
var res1 = dataContext.Persons.Any(p=>p.Name== personName);
```

Comment: I already knew the answer, i was just checking anyone know this or not-> Just kidding.